# Cocos2d-x image not found "already has the suffix -ipad. Using it."

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

So i'm using Cocos2d and i keep getting the error

```
Cocos2d: cocos2d: CCFileUtils: Warning file not found: fps_images-ipad.fnt
Cocos2d: cocos2d: CCFileUtils: Warning file not found: fps_images-ipad.png
Cocos2d: cocos2d: CCFileUtils: Warning file not found: fps_images-ipad.png
Cocos2d: cocos2d: CCFileUtils: Warning file not found: fps_images-ipad.png
Cocos2d: cocos2d: CCFileUtils: Warning file not found: TurkeySprite_v2-ipad.png
Cocos2d: cocos2d: WARNING Filename(TurkeySprite_v2-ipad) already has the suffix -ipad. Using it.
Cocos2d: cocos2d: WARNING Filename(TurkeySprite_v2-ipad) already has the suffix -ipad. Using it.
```

I'm not sure what this all means but I pretty much just started my project and was wondering how I went wrong so quickly.

Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning

```
Cocos2d: cocos2d: CCFileUtils: Warning file not found: fps_images-ipad.fnt
```

means that you tried to display a sprite loading a file name @"fps_images.fnt" and that no iPad specific version for it was found (which would be called @"fps_images-ipad.fnt".

On the other hand, the other warning you get:

```
Cocos2d: cocos2d: WARNING Filename(TurkeySprite_v2-ipad) already has the suffix -ipad. Using it.
```

means that you tried loading an image by specifying its name as: @"TurkeySprite_v2-ipad.png"; since it already contains the `-ipad` suffix you get the warning.

In the first case you can avoid the warning by providing the iPad specific version of the file; in the second case, simply remove `-ipad` from the filename: @"TurkeySprite_v2.png".

In both cases, there is nothing absolutely wrong with both kind of warnings.

Comment: see thats weird because this is how I loaded in my files `_batchNode = CCSpriteBatchNode::batchNodeWithFile("TurkeySprite_v2.png");
    this->addChild(_batchNode);
    CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->addSpriteFramesWithFile("TurkeySprite_v2.plist");`

Comment: and also, just for my understanding, is the `-ipad` tag sorta like the `@2x` tag that is used? Also, why does it care if its for iPad or iPhone, the @2x just tells if it's retina or not

Comment: It's an annoying warning message that is triggered incorrectly in my opinion. This happens in the cocos2d-iphone version, strange they ported that to cocos2d-x as well. To my knowledge the first warning type only occurs when trying to load bitmap fonts, you can ignore that. The second warning is caused by adding "xxxx-ipad.png" images to the texture atlas - only use non-suffixed files in the texture atlas (xxxx.png) to fix it.